# how to write collection_select with nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with nested attributes. I can't get `collection_select` to work. Here's what I have

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :person, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  belongs_to :person, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client
  has_one :contact
  belongs_to :personal_title
  # Returns the combined personal title, first and surname
  def name
    [
      personal_title.nil? ? '' : personal_title.title,
      first_name || '',
      last_name || ''
    ].reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
  end
end
```

In summary, `Client` has a `contact_id` and a `person_id`, `Contact` has a `person_id` and `Person` has a `personal_title_id`. On my form I have

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contact_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:contact_id, Client.all, :id, :name,
    {include_blank: true}) %>
</div>
```

I know where the problem is, but from the documentation I can't work out how to fix it. The error I get is `undefined method 'name' for #<Client:0x6c01350>`. That's correct. name() is declared in Person, not Client. I can get it to work with,

```
<select name="client[contact_id]">
  <% Contact.all.each do |contact| %>
    <option value="<%= contact.id %>"><%= contact.person.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

This works because I have used `contact.person.name`, not `contact.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model Client isnt a method to return the name.
The method to return the name is in the Person class.

Create a method in Client to return the name of the person and it should be work.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :person, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true

  def name
    self.person.name
  end

end
```

Comment: That fixed it. Of course, it seems so obvious now. Thanks.